# Spine JS:: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, callstack, spine.js

**Problem**

I am navigating to a link which is activating my controller.
The maximum call stack is exceeded when executing the line: `@log(Model.all())` within my controller.

`Model.all()` has 0 records
The controller is 28 functions in 4 classes, over 200 lines

**Questions**

- What is a call stack in Spine/JS terms: is it a function? a class? a module?
- Are the call stack limits imposed by the Browser,JS, JQuery or Spine? [possible browser limits](http://novemberborn.net/2007/08/javascriptcallstack-size-120)
- Is this a common problem, and if so how can I avoid it while using Spine JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove that line the app keeps working?

Otherwise I think with that little classes / functions it's more likely to be an issue with your code. I think some function keeps calling itself which causes the stacksize to become too big.

Comment: found the problem. at the end of the model code was an attribute for the related model, causing a loop when called. Cheers for your help